# React Native components name with point parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create custom component in React Native with parameters, ex. : transform `<PageHeader />` to `<Page.Header />` or `<PageContent />` to `<Page.Content />`.

I've see this syntaxe with `Picker` component in React Native.

```js
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.lang}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.switchLang(itemValue)}
  style={Styles.picker}
>
  <Picker.Item label="EN" value="en-EN" />
  <Picker.Item label="FR" value="fr-FR" />
</Picker>
```

Thank you community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write your components exposing the other components as `static class variables` which you can access from the class Instance  for example you define your components like

```
class PageContent extends React.Component {}

class PageHeader extends React.Component {}
```

and then declare your page component like

```
class Page extends React.Component {
   static Content = PageContent;
   static Header = PageHeader;

}

export default Page
```

Now if your import `Page` , you could access `Header` and `Content` like `<Page.Content/>` and `<Page.Header/>`

Now if the `Page` component doesn't do any React stuff, you could instead write it a basic `class`

Answer (score 1):

I used to do it this way:

### Pager.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Pager extends Component {
    ...
}

Pager.Header = class extends Component {
    ...
}
```

Then you can use it in your app. For VSCode it will also show auto complete `Header` after `Pager.`.

### app.js

```js
import { Pager } from './Pager';

<Pager>
    <Pager.Header />
</Pager>
```